# Microsoft Edge returns DNS error, all other browsers work

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am having a persnickety problem with Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.  When I browse to any website in Edge, I receive an error message: "There was a temporary DNS error" with "Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT FOUND".

The same websites can be found in Chrome.  The websites can be properly resolved using nslookup and pinged from a command prompt leading me to believe that this is not a network-related issue.

I've attempted the following:

- Uninstalled and re-installed wireless and Ethernet adapters
- Ensured that "Enable TCP Fast Open" is unchecked in *about:flags*
- Removed the Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe folder from and reinstalled the package using the appropriate PowerShell command.
- Ran ipconfig /flushdns

What steps would you take next to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this machine connected to an Active Directory domain?  *INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT FOUND* is proxy error.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No. Its from a small business with only two computers.  I checked the proxy settings and didn't see any set.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, i found out that Microsoft store was also affected.  I tried removing the Microsoft Account and logging in with a local account.  That did not help.

I reset the store. I tried the troubleshooting tool. I deleted and re-installed the Microsoft Store package. None of those worked.

However, last night, and update had downloaded.  In a last ditch effort, I applied the update and it turned out to be the Creator's Update.  Edge and Store worked after it was installed.